# How to read a binary file in normal text form in C language using read and write methods?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I am taking input from user and writing that input in a test.bin file in binary format. But the things is that I want to read the file in normal text form not in binary format in which it is stored.

I have written the below code but when I read it, it does not show the data in normal text. Please help me out with this. I am new to C language. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char name[15];
    char lastname[15];
    int course;
    char group[15];
};

struct student * input_student()
{
    struct student *data = (struct student*) malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", &data->name);
    printf("Enter lastname:");
    scanf("%s", &data->lastname);
    printf("Enter course:");
    scanf("%d", &data->course);
    printf("Enter group:");
    scanf("%s", &data->group);
    return data;
}

int data_show(int bytes, int fd, const char *file) {
    struct student *data = NULL;
    struct student *tmp;
    int idx = 0;
    int count = 0;
    data = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    while (bytes > 0) {
        bytes = read(fd, data + count, sizeof(struct student));

        if (bytes == -1) {
            printf("File read error: %i (%s)\n",
                    errno, strerror(errno));
            close(fd);
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }

        if (!bytes) {
            break;
        }

        if (bytes < sizeof(struct student)) {
            printf("Error: read %i bytes out of %lu\n",
                    bytes, sizeof(struct student));
            close(fd);
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }
        count++;
        tmp = (struct student *)realloc(data,
                sizeof(struct student) * (count + 1));
        if (!tmp) {
            close(fd);
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }
        data = tmp;
    }
    
    printf("name\tlastname\tcourse\tgroup\n");

    while (count--){
        printf("%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\n", (data + idx)->name,
                (data + idx)->lastname,
                &(data + idx)->course,
                (data + idx)->group);
        idx++;
    }
    printf("Read %i records from %s\n", idx, file);
}

int main ()
{
    int bytes = 1;
    int fd;
    int num;
    struct student *sp;
    const char *file = "test.bin";
    struct student *tmp;

    fd = open(file, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0000777);

    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("File open error: %i (%s)\n",
                    errno, strerror(errno));
        return fd;
    }

    data_show(bytes, fd, file);

    sp = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if (!sp) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    sp = input_student();

    bytes = write(fd, &sp, sizeof(struct student));

    if (bytes == -1) {
        printf("File write error: %i (%s)\n",
                errno, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return bytes;
    }

    printf("Student data saved to %i (%i bytes)\n",
                    fd, bytes);
    free(sp);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I am getting form the above code:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLVeE.png)

Comment: `sp = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));` followed by `sp = input_student();` is a memory-leak because the pointer to the 1st allocated block is overwritten by the return from `input_student();`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, how to deal with it ?

Comment: It's not useful to allocate space for student structure using malloc. In this code it's enough to declare `struct sp student` and to use the structure.

Comment: To save data as text you cannot directly save the binary content of the structure. You may use `fprintf` to write text formatted data onto the file.

Comment: To use fprintf you have to open the file with the `fopen` function.

Answer (score 2):

*How to deal with it?*

There is a lot packed into that question. Obviously, the simple answer is just to choose one location where you will allocate for each new student added to your collection, but I fear that answer would fall well short of providing you with much help at all.

So let's fix things -- starting from the beginning. I will move fairly quickly from a description standpoint as the code is commented reasonably well.

First glaring problem, `15` characters is not nearly enough characters to handle all reasonably anticipated names. Double that at least (but be mindful your struct will contains static arrays and each will require storage for the full size of each array) A reasonable start, eliminating your *Magic Numbers* and hardcoded filesnames could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXGRP   16             /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM    32             /* 15 is inadequate for many names */
#define MAXC   1024

typedef struct student {        /* typedef for convenience */
    char name[MAXNM];
    char lastname[MAXNM];
    int course;
    char group[MAXGRP];
} student;
```

Next since you will be reading character strings and integers for every student entered, go ahead a write a function to read and **validate** string and integer input. You can provide an optional prompt to be output before each input (or provide `NULL` in its place and no prompt is output). To read character strings, or integer input read a complete line of user-input with `fgets()`. So what remains in `stdin` doesn't impact subsequent inputs.

Use a temporary buffer (array) to hold the user input (*don't skimp on buffer size*) and then validate the string will fit in your struct before copying the string:

```
char *getstring (char *str, size_t maxlen, char *prompt)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer to read each user-input */
    size_t len;                             /* length of string read */
    
    for (;;) {                              /* loop continually */
        if (prompt)                         /* display prompt if not NULL */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);
        
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* get string, handle manual EOF */
            puts ("(input canceled)");
            return NULL;
        }
        buf[(len = strcspn(buf,"\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
        
        if (len < maxlen)                   /* validate string fits */
            break;
        
        fputs ("error: input length exceeds storage.\n", stderr);
    }
    
    return memcpy (str, buf, len + 1);      /* copy buf to str, return ptr to str */
}
```

For integer input, do the exact same thing except this time, attempt a conversion to `int` using `sscanf()` and in the event of a *matching failure*, since you took the input using `fgets()`, there is no need to clear to end of line to remove the offending characters before your next attempted read, e.g.

```
int getint (int *val, char *prompt)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer to read each user-input */
    
    for (;;) {                              /* loop continually */
        if (prompt)                         /* display prompt if not NULL */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);
    
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* get string, handle manual EOF */
            puts ("(input canceled)");
            return 0;
        }
        
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", val) == 1)   /* convert to int / validate */
            break;
        
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    
    return 1;       /* return success */
}
```

Now let's change your `getstudent()` function to only be responsible from filling a `struct student` and move all memory allocation to an `addstudent()` function later that will only allocate memory if student data has been successfully stored in a temporary stuct. Your `getstudent()` read would take a pointer to the temporary stuct to fill and return a pointer to that stuct on success or `NULL` on failure, e.g.:

```
student *getstudent (student *s)
{
    putchar ('\n');     /* provide empty line before each set of input */
    
    if (!getstring (s->name, MAXNM, "Enter name: "))            /* read/validate first */
        return NULL;
    
    if (!getstring (s->lastname, MAXNM, "Enter lastname: "))    /* read/validate last */
        return NULL;
    
    if (!getint (&s->course, "Enter course: "))                 /* read/validate course */
        return NULL;
    
    if (!getstring (s->group, MAXGRP, "Enter group: "))         /* read/validate group */
        return NULL;
    
    return s;       /* return pointer to filled struct */
}
```

(**note:** all of your functions that can either succeed or fail should return a type that can be used to validate success or failure of the function)

The logic is kept much clearner by offloading all the validation code to your `getstring()` and `getint()` functions.

Now an `addstudent()` function simply needs to call `getstudent()` and if that succeeds, than allocate (`realloc()`) memory and store the new student in that new memory in your collection. It will also update the total number of students in your collection by taking a pointer to the total number and then incrementing the value at that address, e.g.

```
student *addstudent (student **students, size_t *nstudents)
{
    student s = {.name = ""};       /* declare temporary struct */
    
    if (!getstudent (&s))           /* fill/validate temporary struct */
        return NULL;
    
    /* allocate / validate memory to hold struct */
    void *tmp = realloc (*students, (*nstudents + 1) * sizeof **students);
    if (!tmp) {
        perror ("addstudent-tmp");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    *students = tmp;                /* assign reallocated block to students */
    (*students)[*nstudents] = s;    /* fill new mem with temp struct */
    (*nstudents)++;                 /* increment student count */
    
    return *students;       /* return pointer to students */
}
```

Your showdata function can be greatly simplified to simply iterate over each struct in your collection, outputting data in your chosen format, e.g.:

```
void showdata (student *s, size_t nstudents)
{
    if (!nstudents) {               /* if no students, so indicate */
        puts ("no student data.");
        return;
    }
    
    puts ("\nname\tlastname\tcourse\tgroup");   /* output heading */
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nstudents; i++)      /* loop outputting each student */
        printf ("%s\t%-8s\t%d\t%s\n", s[i].name, s[i].lastname, s[i].course, s[i].group);
}
```

Now to load students from a file into your collection, you will use an approach similar to `addstudent()` you will read from the file into a temporary struct and then only on a successful read do you allocate storage from that struct and add it to your collection.

---

**NOTE** this is not in practice how you write and read struct data to/from a file. Why? The compiler is free to insert padding bytes in between or after any of the members of your struct (but not before the first) and there is nothing in the C standard that mandates where and how much padding a compiler will add. That means that writing a series of stuct to a binary file is completely non-portable between compilers (but for learning purposes it should work fine on the same computer -- the same compiler should at least be consistent in what it does) In practice you will *serialize* the data before writing it out in binary, so you can read the same data back in in a portable manner.

---

At this point, just be away you can't write arrays of structs to a binary file and have that file read back in by another compiler due to potential differences in padding.

With that said, on your same computer, you can read the collection of `struct student` into memory with the following:

```
student *loadstudents (int fd, student **students, size_t *nstudents)
{
    for (;;) {                      /* loop continually reading students from file */
        student s;                  /* temporary struct */
        ssize_t nbytes;             /* no. of bytes read */
        errno = 0;                  /* reset errno */
        
        nbytes = read (fd, &s, sizeof **students);  /* read student into temp struct */
        if (nbytes == -1) {                         /* validate no error */
            perror ("loadstudents-read");
            return NULL;
        }
        if (nbytes != sizeof **students) {          /* validate no. of bytes read */
            if (nbytes != 0)
                fputs ("error: less than student no. of bytes read.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        
        /* allocate / validate memory to hold struct */
        void *tmp = realloc (*students, (*nstudents + 1) * sizeof **students);
        if (!tmp) {
            perror ("loadstudents-tmp");
            return NULL;
        }
        *students = tmp;                /* assign reallocated block to students */
        (*students)[*nstudents] = s;    /* fill new mem with temp struct */
        (*nstudents)++;                 /* increment student count */
    }
    
    return *students;       /* return pointer to students */
}
```

Writing the collection of `struct student` to the file in binary in a non-poratable way is trivial. You know how many students you have, and you know how many bytes per-struct your compiler provides for each struct, so you just write `number * sizeof (struct student)` bytes to the file, e.g.

```
int writestudents (int fd, student *students, size_t nstudents)
{
    ssize_t nbytes = sizeof *students * nstudents;      /* no. of bytes to write */
    
    return write (fd, students, nbytes) == nbytes;      /* write/validate bytes written */
}
```

Those are your functions and their uses in a nutshell. Now just write a `main()` function that will read what is already present in your datafile (which you provide the name of as an argument to `main()` and do NOT hardcode it -- that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for). You add any student in the file to your collection saving the number of students loaded from file so you don't need to worry about writing them out again since you have your file opened `O_RDWR`. (it would be simpler to open it `O_RDONLY`, read all the students into your collection in memory, close the file and when you are ready to write the file, open it `O_WRONLY` and write all the students out)

After loading all the students from your file, you call `addstudent()` and add any additional students you like (or none at all if you generate a manual `EOF` at a data entry prompt)

To write your collection out at the end (instead of writing each new struct out piecemeal) you simply write all new structs you have added at the end and then close the file (checking the return of `close()` to catch any flush or stream errors not present when the last struct was written) and then free your data and your done.

You can do that many, many ways, but one approach is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char *file = NULL, buf[MAXC];           /* pointer to filename & temp buffer (y/n) */
    int fd;                                 /* file descriptor */
    size_t nstudents = 0, loaded = 0;       /* total students, no. loaded from file */
    student *students = NULL;               /* pointer to students */
    mode_t mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;      /* open mode */
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate one argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient arguments provided\n"
                        "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    
    file = argv[1];     /* assign filename to pointer */
    fd = open (file, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, mode);    /* open file */
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror ("open-file");
        return 1;
    }
    loadstudents (fd, &students, &loaded);
    if (errno)
        return 1;
    
    nstudents = loaded;     /* assign no. of students loaded (saving loaded) */
    
    if (nstudents)  /* if students read from file, output number */
        printf ("%zu students read from file: %s\n", nstudents, file);
    
    do {    /* loop adding students to collection */
        if (!addstudent (&students, &nstudents))
            break;
        fputs ("\nenter another student (y/n)? ", stdout);  /* prompt to enter more? */
        if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;
    } while (*buf != 'n' && *buf != 'N');   /* while 1st char in buf now 'n/N' */
    
    showdata (students, nstudents);         /* output all in students */
    
    if (nstudents - loaded) {   /* if new students added since file loaded */
        /* write new students added to file */
        if (writestudents (fd, students + loaded, nstudents - loaded))
            printf ("\n%zu students written to file: %s\n", nstudents, file);
        else
            perror ("writestudents");
    }
    
    if (close (fd) == -1)           /* always validate close after write */
        perror ("close-file");
    
    if (nstudents)                  /* free allocated memory */
        free (students);
}
```

That's it, you can just copy/paste all the pieces above together, compile and test. If you look at the code, most of the additions to the code are ***validating*** the return of every user-input function and every allocation. That is mandatory. Type an `"a100"` for the `course` in your code and see what happens...

You validate every allocation because it isn't a matter of ***if*** an allocation can fail, it is a matter of ***when*** an allocation fails. That is why I originally said simply moving all your allocations to a single location would likely not provide a meaningful answer for all of the problems that needed to be addressed in your code.

**Example Use/Output**

Starting wth no data file present, let's add two students and write them to your file:

```
$ ./bin/student_input dat/student_input.bin

Enter name: John
Enter lastname: Doe
Enter course: 100
Enter group: 1000

enter another student (y/n)? y

Enter name: Mickey
Enter lastname: Mouse
Enter course: 101
Enter group: 1002

enter another student (y/n)? n

name    lastname        course  group
John    Doe             100     1000
Mickey  Mouse           101     1002

2 students written to file: dat/student_input.bin
```

Now verify that they are written to your binary file:

```
$ hexdump -Cv dat/student_input.bin
00000000  4a 6f 68 6e 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |John............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  44 6f 65 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Doe.............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  64 00 00 00 31 30 30 30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |d...1000........|
00000050  00 00 00 00 4d 69 63 6b  65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Mickey......|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 4d 6f 75 73  65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Mouse.......|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 65 00 00 00  31 30 30 32 00 00 00 00  |....e...1002....|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
000000a8
```

Looks good, now let's run the program again and add another student:

```
$ ./bin/student_input dat/student_input.bin
2 students read from file: dat/student_input.bin

Enter name: Minnie
Enter lastname: Mouse
Enter course: 101
Enter group: 1004

enter another student (y/n)? n

name    lastname        course  group
John    Doe             100     1000
Mickey  Mouse           101     1002
Minnie  Mouse           101     1004

3 students written to file: dat/student_input.bin
```

Now verify your file contains all three:

```
$ hexdump -Cv dat/student_input.bin
00000000  4a 6f 68 6e 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |John............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  44 6f 65 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Doe.............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  64 00 00 00 31 30 30 30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |d...1000........|
00000050  00 00 00 00 4d 69 63 6b  65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Mickey......|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 4d 6f 75 73  65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Mouse.......|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 65 00 00 00  31 30 30 32 00 00 00 00  |....e...1002....|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  4d 69 6e 6e 69 65 00 00  |........Minnie..|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  4d 6f 75 73 65 00 00 00  |........Mouse...|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  65 00 00 00 31 30 30 34  |........e...1004|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00              |............|
000000fc
```

All there.

Granted this ended up longer than originally planned, but there really isn't any way to provide a 1/2 answer and not leave you with just as many problems as you came with (sans one or two). Big takeaways - take all user-input using `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) so what remains in `stdin` is not conditioned on a `scanf()` conversion, or a *matching failure*, always *validate, validate, validate*, consider using the stdio file-stream functions instead of the low-level syscalls (`read`, `write`, etc..) and don't try and cram all data entry and validation and allocation and counting in a single function -- break it up into smaller, more easily maintained functions -- it will help keep your logic clear.

Look it over, digest it, and let me know if you have further questions.